# Restart asp.net MVC 6 Application

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to figure out hot to restart a MVC6 application.    I have this code snippet that stops it, but it errors out.

```
private readonly IApplicationShutdown applicationShutdown;
public AdminController(IApplicationShutdown applicationShutdown)
{
    this.applicationShutdown = applicationShutdown;
}

public IActionResult RestartApplication()
{
    this.applicationShutdown.RequestShutdown();
}
```

Here gives this error.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationShutdown' ...

Answer (score 3):

The new `IApplicationShutdown` interface replaces the obsolete `IApplicationLifetime` interface (refer to: [Proof link](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/400)).

Use `IApplicationLifetime.StopApplication()` method for terminating the application.

```
private readonly IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime;
public AdminController(IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    this.applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
}

public IActionResult RestartApplication()
{
    this.applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
}
```

But keep in mind that after terminating the application you have to start the application process again.

Comment: 50% answered...  This works to stop the application, but how can it be restarted programmatically?

Comment: Let me give a little more background.  I want to swap (and swap back) to a minified view folder on the fly.  I figure I can implement a custom Razor View engine to do this, but once the application is started it seems that the path is cached somewhere.  I figure restarting the app would allow me to accomplish this, but this could possibly be an idiotic way to do this...

Comment: About reastart process after terminating - you need wrapper around dnx.exe which will be do restart. I don't know about this.

Comment: Did you look at dnx-watch? About dnx-watch you can read at [announce beta 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx)